# Anaconda not found in ZSh?

Tags: python, macos, ipython, anaconda, zsh

I installed Anaconda via command line. The bash file.

If Im in bash, I can open and use anaconda, like notebooks, ipython, etc.

If I change my shell to ZSH, all the anaconda commands appear like "not found".

How I can make it work in zsh?

I use a Mac with OSx Sierra.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I had a similar issue.

I checked in my `.profile`, `.bashrc`, and `.bash_profile` dot files in order to find any PATH information that I could copy over into my `.zshrc` file. Sure enough:

```
# added by Miniconda3 4.2.12 installer
export PATH="/Users/username/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

After running `source ~/.zshrc` with those lines added, I could fire up my jupyter notebook server.

Comment: @marz
as temporary solution, you could active bash environment by typing `source .bashrc` and then go back to "oh my zsh" environment by typing `source zshrc` command.
after that conda will work perfect. 
or you can fire single commnad 
`source .bashrc && source .zshrc`

Comment: on MacOS, this worked for me by adding the line you have to my `~/.bash_profile`, even though it wasn't there in the first place.

Answer (score 155):

Altough I cannot test it on a Mac, (I have a Linux Zsh installed) this should work for you as well: Just execute

```
/(your conda installation path)/bin/conda init zsh
```

and restart your zsh shell. The init command will change your ~/.zshrc file accordingly, setting your PATH correctly and slightly change the PS1 (which is was most answers here do manually...).

Comment: I can confirm that this solution works in MacOS. This is in my opinion the easiest and cleanest solution

Comment: That's actually what is recommended in their [docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html#using-with-fish-shell) just replace `fish` with `zsh` or your desired shell.

Comment: It seems that anaconda will now activate and show the default environment "base", all i wanted was to get the anaconda bin into my path.

Comment: Worked for me. My anaconda3 installation was in ~/opt/anaconda3

Comment: Worked like charm in macOS. best and cleanest solution

Comment: @Moulde I also simply wanted to have conda as another option to my pip installation in `/Library/Frameworks` - so, I had to add aliases to `.zshrc`

Comment: actually, if one wants conda as a second option to another installation, using `conda config --set auto_activate_base false` turns off the auto activate, thus when you open a new shell, conda distribution is not active by default

Comment: This is the best solution so far

Comment: `conda init --help` shows you could do a `conda init --all -d` to do a dry run on seeing what shells it would try to update, and `conda init --all` to actually do the work.

Comment: @marz this should be the 2022's accepted answer...

Comment: After sifting through countless failed solutions, this one finally fixed the problem for me. Thank you.

Comment: I agree with @JPCF: this is the right way for 2022+. Additionally, if you're on an m1 mac and still having trouble, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66296640/how-to-install-anaconda-through-home-brew-m1-mac/66296716#66296716)

Answer (score 20):

This worked for me on my macOS

https://medium.com/@sumitmenon/how-to-get-anaconda-to-work-with-oh-my-zsh-on-mac-os-x-7c1c7247d896

---

Open the .bash_profile file using:

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

There’s a block of code the anaconda installer added to the end of the file. Copy that.

Mine looks something like this:

```
# added by Anaconda3 5.3.0 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
```

Now open your .zshrc file:

```
open ~/.zshrc
```

paste the copied code at the end and save it. Then RUN the below command,

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

When on iterm2 or the terminal, you should see a `(base)` pop up in there

Comment: Worked for me as well.

Answer (score 15):

Since [conda 4.4.0](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#440-2017-12-20) (released 2017-12-20), the recommended way to add conda to your PATH has changed. Instead of the approach described [in Jonathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46902080/2862719), this should be done using the `conda.sh` script in the `etc/profile.d/` folder of your conda installation. After that you can activate the base environment. More information on why this is the case can be found in the conda [changelog](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master).

I needed to add the following lines to my `.zshrc`:

```
.  ~/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate base
```

This assumes that (mini)conda was installed with default parameters, i.e. into the home folder.

Answer (score 10):

Following up on @m00am's answer, as of Anaconda 4.5.11, the `bash` code Anaconda adds to `.bashrc` seems to run perfectly well also in `zsh`, so copying that into your `.zshrc` works well. In my case, the code looked like this:

```
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/home/my-account/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/my-account/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/my-account/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/home/my-account/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
```

Answer (score 10):

If you stumbled here after that you changed your terminal from bash to zsh because you upgraded macOS from Sierra to Catalina, a slight change from Sebastian Thees's answer will make the job.

First, switch back to bash with

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

where your old conda environments are all nicely active. Then, activate conda on zsh with

```
conda init zsh
```

and finally switch back to zsh with

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

No fuss in tracking your conda installation folder this way, which is a plus for a memory-less person like myself.

Comment: I think this would be better voted, it doesn't rely on manual editing init files... In my case, I just evoked /bin/bash directly, used 'conda init zsh' and closing/reopening terminal have done all magic. Thank you.

Comment: Glad that it was of help!

Comment: You can avoid the shell switching thing if you call your conda explicitly.  I tried a `~/anaconda3/bin/conda init zsh` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

Directly from the
[Anaconda Installation Documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/mac-os/#using-the-command-line-install):

If you are on macOS Catalina, the new default shell is zsh. You will instead need to run:

`source <path to conda>/bin/activate`

followed by:

`conda init zsh`

Unfortunately for some reason, this is only mentioned in the command line install section. If you had installed from GUI you still need to do this.

Answer (score 5):

From their docs (This worked for me): If you are on macOS Catalina, the new default shell is zsh. You will instead need to run `source <path to conda>/bin/activate` followed by `conda init zsh`.

For my specific installation (Done by double clicking the installer), this ended up being `source /opt/anaconda3/bin/activate`

Answer (score 4):

**This solution worked for me on macOS Mojave**

If you use version `2019.03` of Anaconda you can update your `.zshrc` file with

```
# Anaconda
. /anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate base
```

after saving file don't forget to run `source ~/.zshrc`.

**After upgrading to Catalina**

If you install a new Anaconda3 2019.07 you can use solution below.

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

Copy the line starts with `# added by Anaconda3 2019.07 installer` and ends with `# <<< conda init <<<` and paste into `.zshrc`. Then run `source ~/.zshrc`.

Comment: this is the correct way to do things for [Anaconda >= 4.4](https://www.anaconda.com/how-to-get-ready-for-the-release-of-conda-4-4/)

Comment: I got:  toly@Tolys-MacBook-Pro-4 ~ % source ~/.zshrc
source: no such file or directory: /Users/toly/.zshrc.  What should I do?

Comment: Do you have oh-my-zsh installed on your machine https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh

Comment: When i copy the anaconda block into .zshrc, and run source ~/.zshrc my terminal changes to (base) as it seems to activate the default anaconda environment called base. All I'm trying to do is be able to run jupyter via zsh terminal. I fixed it by changing adding "export PATH="/Users/USERNAME/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"" in my .zshrc

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your path variable for the ZSH environment. The easy way to do this would be to set your path variable in your .zshrc file to include the location of Anaconda. To get the path in your bash terminal type `which anaconda`

You can also [check](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3428/share-aliases-and-path-setting-between-zsh-and-bash) this out from http://unix.stackexchange.com

[Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.)](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/)

Answer (score 0):

in my original profile, which is .bash_profile, it looks like this:

```
### added by Anaconda3 4.4.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/myname/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

and now i open the file .zshrc, add the sentence above to it, it goes all right now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after I **installed anaconda3 in ubuntu**.

This is how I solved it:

1) I changed to bash and anaconda can work

2) I changed to zsh, and anaconda works. I don't know why, but I think you can try.

Answer (score 0):

In .bashrc

```
zsh
```

In .zshrc

```
conda activate base
```

all **exports** should be resolved

> only if you do not use **chsh**

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem while installing conda with brew on mac M1/M2. adding paths in the `~/.zshrc` didint work either, so I uninstalled conda with `brew install anaconda`  and then installed conda from [the official website](https://www.anaconda.com/download-success) and it worked. No need to add any env vars or any thing in this approach.