# zsh command not found: conda after upgrading to Catalina and even after reinstalling Anaconda

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, conda, zsh

I recently updated my MacOS to Catalina, and now I have the infamous "zsh command not found: conda" when I enter "conda" in my terminal. I've read a number of solutions, and the easiest for me to try was to reinstall Anaconda in my home directory (specifically, the 2019.10 version of the installer installs in Users/myname/opt/anaconda3), as suggested by the folks at Anaconda [here](https://www.anaconda.com/how-to-restore-anaconda-after-macos-catalina-update/).

Well, I did just that and it did not solve the problem. What am I missing?

Comment: Conda installs scripts for bash, but not zsh. The easiest way is to fire up bash, and run `conda init zsh` (from bash)  this will put the appropriate code in you zsh profile (you'll need to start a new terminal session).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I switched my user account to bash and found that conda ran immediately without additional work. I guess that's because conda runs on bash. But I did the zsh switch as you suggested, and the conda command works now on zsh.

Comment: Glad it worked.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the [Anaconda install docs](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/mac-os/):

> In order to initialize after the installation process is done, first run `source <path to conda>/bin/activate` and then run `conda init`.

However,

> If you are on **macOS Catalina**, the new default shell is zsh. You will instead need to run `source <path to conda>/bin/activate` followed by **`conda init zsh`**.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did as suggested by the install docs and it works fine now.

Comment: Yup the activation is the problem after installation this step should be automatic

Comment: please feel free to mark the answer as accepted the clicking the tick.

Comment: This worked for me too -- should be accepted, I spent some time on other answers which didn't help @AshtonT.Sperry

Answer (score 0):

I tried in Macbook M1 Air with the following command.

```
(your conda installation path)/bin/conda init zsh
```

Example:

```
/Users/<username>/opt/anaconda3//bin/conda init zsh
```

Then restarted the terminal and executed the command

```
conda activate base
```

It worked perfectly

Source command is taken is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40370467/anaconda-not-found-in-zsh)

Answer (score 0):

After installing miniconda on macos, we need to initialize the zsh. Different from the command `~/miniconda3/bin/conda init` for the legacy bash, we need to add zsh in the end, i.e., `~/miniconda3/bin/conda init zsh`. Then restart the terminal.