# How to install anaconda through home-brew m1 mac

Tags: macos, anaconda, homebrew, apple-m1

I just got an m1 Mac and installed anaconda using home-brew:

```
brew install anaconda
```

It looked like it worked great, except that when I actually go to use anaconda and type "conda" I get the dreaded "conda command not found" error. How do I fix this?

Based on the answer given by @Peter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52664293/why-or-why-not-add-anaconda-to-path/52664684) as well as the anaconda documentation, adding to path is no longer recommended. The [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40370467/anaconda-not-found-in-zsh) also did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Figured it out! Challenge lay in the home-brew path. To run the conda init zsh command, detailed by @Sebastian [in the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40370467/anaconda-not-found-in-zsh), I had to specify home-brew, as well as back up a couple directories. The command that actually got it done in terminal was:

```
~/../../opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin/conda init zsh
```

Happy home-brew anaconda-ing on your new m1s everyone.

Comment: why the `~/../..` prefix? That's just white noise and just saying go 2 directories up from user home `~` directory... which if you think about it is equivalent to `/`. So long story short, that whole `~/../..` part probably can be removed, as its not really doing anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue when installing `condo` on my Mac M2 with `brew` e.g. **homebrew**.

Complete list of steps I ran, to resolve that:

```
$ brew install anaconda
...
PREFIX=/opt/homebrew/anaconda3
...
$ /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/bin/conda init $(basename $SHELL)
modified      /Users/ritvik/.zshrc

==> For changes to take effect, close and re-open your current shell. <==
```

***N.B.*** when running `brew install anaconda`, `brew` itself prints the folder path to anaconda installation in the terminal. You can see it in above:

```
PREFIX=/opt/homebrew/anaconda3
```

Just tack on a `/bin/conda` to that directory, and one will locate the `condo` executable path.

Answer (score 0):

Conda installer adds a script in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` file

you simple need to load it so it get initialized, you can do that with

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

if you are using zsh or

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Or close the terminal and open a new one.