Why can't I access python from a conda environment?
I wanted to use python inside a conda environment. I was expecting that if I ran the command python then python would start up. What actually happened what that python was not found: see below.
From conda base, I can access python
If I create a new environment, I get the following
(base) x@y ~ % conda create --name test
....
(base) x@y ~ % conda activate test
(test) x@y ~ % python
zsh: command not found: python
(test) x@y ~ % conda install python
Channels:
 - defaults
Platform: osx-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
(test) x@y ~ % python
zsh: command not found: python

Any ideas for how to allow the environment to use python? Intel Mac Sonoma 14.5, zsh.

Try the top answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40370467/anaconda-not-found-in-zsh this is many times the issue (i.e., you need to init your shell so it is set up to properly "find" things in your conda environments) ... if the top answer doesn't work, try some of the other answers :) I feel like it might be as simple as conda init zsh (followed by a restart of the shell) ...

Thanks so much for your answer! I have done conda init zsh + restart and also checked my .zshrc, but does not solve this issue.
However, I have solved the problem. As long as I do conda create --name test2 python=3.12 (or whatever version), it does install python in the environment.

Creating a conda environment does NOT automatically include Python.  Conda is general environment manager.  You can have Python conda environments, R conda environments, Julia conda environments, etc.
You must specify that you want Python as well when you create it.
conda create -n test python

If you want an R environment, you can use:
conda create -n r-env r-base

For Julia:
conda create -n julia-env julia

Neither the R, nor the Julia envs have Python.  Just like the Python env does not have R or Julia.  An empty conda envirnment, is just that: empty.

Thanks, I realised this myself eventually! Not sure why I had so much trouble this time around as have been using conda for years but there we go.
